# css gradient 1 color fill 40px and another fill calc(100%-40px)

Tags: css, gradient

I am working on a project. In that project I need a gradient background for a div.  I need a color to fill only 40px. another color fill calc(100%-40px). I never played with gradient so deeply. my 40px color is `rgba(51,51,51,0.44)` and 100%-40px color is `rgba(51,51,51,0.3)`.
 Here I created a image 
 [image: here I created a image] 
Is it possible? if not any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, you just set the first color to stop after 40px, and then the second color to start at the same point and continue to the end.

Format :

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, grey, grey 40px, red 40px, red);
linear-gradient([direction], [first color], [first color] [color-stop point], [second color] [second color start point], [optional]);
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, grey, grey 40px, red 40px);
}
.short {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div class="short"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks [Paulie_D](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) for your help. It works! But only on modern browsers. any way to get supported in older browsers?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by older browsers but I'm sure there are polyfils you can use. - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: it doesn't support 0n IE8 and older. How can I convert this new browsers supported css to IE and other older browsers like chrome 10-25, firefox 3.6-15,opera 11 and Safari 5.1-6 old version supported css? I pasted this css to colorzilla and colorzilla give me some css. But they have problem because it don't show like what i wanted.

Comment: If a browser doesn't support gradients there not much you can do.